# Help with the derivation of a variant of Coulomb's Law

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields, coulombs-law

My E&M textbook says the following:
The electric field at position $r= (x,y,z)$ generated by a point charge $q$ at the origin is given by $$\vec{E}(r) =\frac{q}{4π\epsilon_0r^2}\hat r=\frac{q}{4π\epsilon_0}\frac{x\hat i+y\hat j+z\hat k}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
I understand Coulomb's Law, but how is the right side of the equation derived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electric field generated by a point charge is radial, which means the $\hat{i}$ on the left should actually be:
\begin{equation}
\hat{r}=\frac{\vec{r}}{r}=\frac{x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}
\end{equation}